# Conversion Tracking with Firebase Analytics and UTM on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, utm

I need to implement conversion tracking on my android app using firebase analytics.

In order to do that I will add some UTM parameters to my links, and that links will open a screen on my android app (using deep linking) and then I think I will need to send those parameters to Firebase.

What I want to know is what is the right/common approach to do this?
Should I parse the URL on opening the app, save the UTM parameters and send them later when a conversion occurs?

How shold I send them to Firebase? Using an extra parameter or user properties?

If a conversion occur after an year, does it make sense to send the UTM parameters to firebase as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Analytics automatically extracts those URLs with utm_* params and logs campaign events. When a conversion event occurs, they will also automatically attribute to the correct campaign events, so you don't have to parse the URL.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm not talking about installations but deep linking.. for example, a link that will open a list of products or a product detail on my e-commerce app.

Comment: if a URL opens your app and it contains utm_ * params like utm_campaign or utm_source, it will log a campaign event with those params. You can turn on debug mode and see for yourself on DebugView. If you want to do it manually, you can parse the URL and log a CAMPAIGN_DETAILS with those params (See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#CAMPAIGN_DETAILS)

Comment: so if I need to track a custom parameter with a different name, the right approach is to log that event?

Comment: Yes, you should use the CAMPAIGN_DETAILS to do so. Note that there are some required event parameters and optional parameters so don't miss the required ones. Otherwise, your attribution may be off as the campaign events could be disregarded.