# React Native firebase analytics app install tracking

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

For Example, i am using react-native-firebase library.
I want to grow my app install and i create a campaign.
The question is how can i know my app is installed by clicking ads or my app is downloaded directly on play store.
Simply i want to know where was my app downloaded from. I do implement firebase analytics configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could follow the advice given in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47893179/4147687

Essentially, if all you want is simply a way to track how your app was installed, you can simply pass utm parameters along with your URL.

For example:
`https://link-to-my-app.com/?utm_source=business_card&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=sign_up_offer`

Google Play has it's own URL builder to make this step easier [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder).  If you are not using any specific ad network just set it as "Custom".

Firebase will automatically scrape the source, campaign and medium parameters there and present them to you in the first_open conversion event.  Documentation for how this works is [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en#custom).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using this npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-install-referrer

1. You should invoke the API only once during the first execution after install.
2. You can do that using AsyncStorage to check if its freshly installed or not and then you can logEvent based on that UTM url and track the users
3. After creating the event you can segregate users by creating Audiences in the firebase console.

Comment: Is that possible to do this for ios also?

Comment: No its not possible in IOS using above package

Comment: Are there any available libraries for iOS currently or is it possible to capture the link from the app install?